# sequelize find data that is associated

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have 2 models **Prophet** and **Task** and they have a **m:n** relationship:

**Prophets**

```
const prophet = sequelize.define('prophets', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true
    }
});
prophet.relationship = function(task) {
    prophet.belongsToMany(task, {
        through: 'prophetTasks',
        as: 'tasks',
        foreignKey: 'prophetName'
    });
};
```

**Tasks**

```
const task = sequelize.define('tasks', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true
    }
});
task.relationship = function(prophet) {
    task.belongsToMany(prophet, {
        through: 'prophetTasks',
        as: 'prophets',
        foreignKey: 'taskName'
    });
};
```

EDITED:
*my problem is sometimes I have to update a prophet which might remove some relationships with tasks, but I cant figure out how to delete the tasks that have no more relationship with any prophets.*

I believe I should find all tasks that doesnt belong in **prophetTasks** table anymore, but I dont know how to query that with sequelize

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `ON DELETE CASCADE`

So whenever the row is deleted, data containing it as a foreign key will be deleted.

Comment: sorry I messed up my question. I meant update prophets, not delete them :\